# local variable updates globally in java

Tags: java, variables

I call function ***move*** with 2 dimensional array full of zeros at point **[6, 5]** which has value **0**. The function increases the value to **1**.

Then the same function call itself again ***move(x - 1, y, map, i)***, which means it is at point **[5, 5]** with value **0**, which it increases to **1** and ends itself.

But why was the ***map*** variable updated also in the function, which was called first?

```
private static byte[10][10] myMap = {*all zeros*};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    move(6, 5, myMap, 0);
}

private static void move(int x, int y, byte[][] map, int i) {
    if (map[x][y] == 0) {
        map[x][y]++;
        i++;
    }
    if (i > 1) return;

    System.out.print(x + " " + y);
    // 6 5
    System.out.print(map[5][5] + " " + i);
    // 0 1
    move(x - 1, y, map, i);

    System.out.print(map[5][5] + " " + i);
    // 1 1 ... WTH? Shouldn't this return 0 1 like above?
}
```

And when it updates the ***map***, why it doesn't update the ***i*** variable?

I'm struggling hours to find why, but still don't know:/
Thanks for help

Comment: What about `private static byte[][] myMap = new byte[10][10]`? Note that in Java arrays will always be initialized to `false`, `0` or `null`.

Comment: I've updated the some example in the answer for using your map, but in the end you may want to create a `Board` class that uses the `byte[][]` as field (or cal it `GameMap`, but not `Map` as that is a heavily used class from `java.util`).

Comment: @owlstead Thanks, I just needed the cloneMap function.. Since I'm not doing any game, I don't have to store the maps, the only thing I care about is the **i** and time how long it takes to travel considering the robot I'm building this for.. I deleted all the methods and stuff around just to show my problem ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be confusing at first sight, but it is very easy to understand when you understand passing by reference and passing by value.

Array variables consist of a reference to the actual array. Basically they are treated the same as objects. This means that you are updating the map that you give to the function.

`int` variables are primitive types (`int`, `short`, `byte`, `long`, `char`, `float`, `double` and of course `boolean` - note the initial lowercase character in the names), which are passed by value in Java. Basically a copy of the value is made. So you can never use such a variable to return any value. You need a `return` statement if you want to do that.

---

For example:

```
// using depth first, then width!!!
private static byte[][] myMap = new byte[10][10];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    move(6, 5, myMap, 0);
}

private static byte[][] cloneMap(byte[][] map) {
    byte[][] newMap = new byte[map.length][];
    for (int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
        newMap[x] = map[x].clone();
    }
    return newMap;
}

private static void printMap(byte[][] map) {
    for (int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < map[0].length; y++) {
            System.out.printf("%3d ", map[x][y] & 0xFF);
        }
        System.out.printf("%n");
    }
}

private static int move(int x, int y, byte[][] map, int i) {
    if (map[x][y] == 0) {
        map[x][y]++;
        i++;
    }
    if (i > 1) return i;

    System.out.printf("x: %d, y: %d%n", x, y);
    // 6 5

    printMap(map);
    System.out.printf("i: %d%n", i);

    // -- note, you may still be missing some way of storing the maps
    map = cloneMap(map);
    i = move(x - 1, y, map, i);

    // System.out.println(map[5][5] + " " + i);
    printMap(map);
    System.out.printf("i: %d%n", i);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! But how to pass that array by value?

Comment: @Dev no. Everything is pass by value.

Comment: @owlstead My bad, I flipped it (in fairness you did as well before you edited which tripped me up). My point was that primitives and objects are handled the same way pass-by-value, just primitives by their nature are immutable. Either way +1 for the explanation.

Comment: @owlstead I'm sorry, but I'm not sure how you meant it. Could you quickly show it? Thank you ;)

Comment: @Dev     In Java, everything is passed by Value. You pass the copy of the object's reference in the function argument.

Comment: @owlstead Thank you, I didn't know how to implement the cloneMap fn only ;)

Comment: @hagubear I understand this, the whole stream of comments is a misunderstanding. I copied an error owlstead made in the original post without realizing it while commenting on a different but related point and it made me look bad. Three people have been by to tell me so :(. It was an honest mistake, I swear!